# Sendgrid: How to remove the very long link at the end of the email?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

There's a very long link at the end of the email.  I send my email relay through Sendgrid API, however, there's a long link at the end of the email, which is look ugly and it make my customer suspicious about the email.

My question, how can I stop that email from automatically added to my mail?

Here's an example:

```
You have received an enquiry through Fisher on the page CONTACT US at http://u32344.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=-2FH2LMikN-
2FrM6GSYF4LOpzROzbb98IylqLWruds0yLWDlskXfQwEEpqM-2FGspZe3ngXB1kz-2Fda-2FKJ45LJ33Q-3D-
3D_CdoX6Ut6sjBIH5b9s6-2B4KLBssXGg5MSKcTXJ2np8SXO8HlDjX5gYeRYEMHb10cuZ1IFBl85i7423sBDgs42s9CLpxGa-
2FlLoCMLUV7LfNRvBixLKSJSDN5LkBGvMablz7ImUB-2FKw1jtx0wtR8bDbIbucvag7-2BVVfVoO25xMi-
2FgFoTcFHL9EswzkYPPKYnjaeAbq90Wja9aPq8-2Fz-2FBsw4GqJ0-2FhvHVOO3zY8GKStz2iyxWxJsfm4YZkuGxlxXF
```

Comment: i think that it is a verification key for security purpose you can't remove it, because it works like a signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sending the email as text or html?

If the link is appearing as text like that I assume your mail client is "in text mode" and not "html mode".

That long link is an artifact from using click tracking. Turn off click tracking to revert to the original "shorter" URL you want.